# помогите с кодом JavaScript, событие на нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. помогите с кодом JavaScript

Есть три кнопки.Необходимо при нажатии кнопки but1 выпрыгивал слой div1, при нажатии кнопки but2 выпрыгивал слой div2 и.т.д

```
<p style="font-size: 24px; color: #26E442; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">
   <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="but1"> 
   <input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="but2">
   <input type="button" name="button2" id="button3" value="but3">
</p>
```

Comment: Откуда и куда выпрыгивал? Где код div'ов?

Comment: @humster_spb прыгнуть в котел с кипятком, потом в котел с  кипящим молоком и затем окунуться в ледяную воду.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, тут сложная css-анимация требуется :))

Answer (score 0):

Один из простых вариантов:

```js
var arrayOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var arrayOfDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div')

arrayOfButtons.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', click);
});

function click() {
  arrayOfDivs.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.classList.contains('invisible') && item.getAttribute('id').slice(item.id.length - 1) - 1 == event.target.id.slice(event.target.id.length - 1) - 1) {
      item.classList.remove('invisible');
    } else {
      item.classList.add('invisible');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="invisible">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="invisible">div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="invisible">div3</div>
<p style="font-size: 24px; color: #26E442; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">
  <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="but1">
  <input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="but2">
  <input type="button" name="button2" id="button3" value="but3">
</p>
```

Нужно рассмотреть конктретную ситуацию, чтобы точнее выразить ответ.

Comment: почему в одном случае используется `item.getAttribute('id')`, в другом - `item.id`. Вызов slice можно упростить до `.slice(-1)`. Зачем вычитать из результата единицу?

Comment: Можно, задумался...